# Add Symbol () in report ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008

I have code :
CourseName + ' ' + isnull(GradeLevel,'')) as CourseName
The result :
Permit Working High 3

How to make result like this :
Permit Working High (3)

Answer (score 1):

```
CourseName + ' ' + 
    CASE 
        WHEN GradeLevel IS NULL THEN '' 
        ELSE '(' + GradeLevel + ')' 
    END 
AS CourseName
```